# Is this Google Picker warning irrelevant?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-caja, google-picker

When I deliver a completed development I like to try to ensure I have zero reports appearing in browser console logs, but Google Picker in Google Chrome is putting out some that I can't understand, much less eliminate.

In Chrome :

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://docs.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://script.google.com'). rpc.js?c=1&container=onepick:449(anonymous function) rpc.js?c=1&container=onepick:449
>
> Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fscript…yM00%22%7D))&rpctoken=j40k2vrtblzp&rpcService=web4u667ke9q&thirdParty=true': 'ALLOW-FROM https://script.google.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.

I see nothing similar in Firefox developer console, except for the following, seemingly unrelated, message :

> NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO:  unity-global-property-initializer.js:238

Using Google Picker in my GAS script seems to work correctly in every other way.

Is there something I can do to eliminate those warning?

Are they trying to tell me something I ought to be taking seriously?

Answer (score 0):

If it's working correctly I don't think you need to worry about it. It's probably a misconfiguration in Apps Script or perhaps a problem introduced by Caja sanitization.